# Visual Basic: IsNothing() function with Guid values

Tags: vb.net, value-type

I bumped into the following legacy VB code (`customerId` is Guid):

> ```
> If IsNothing(customerID) Or (customerID.Equals(System.Guid.Empty)) Then
>     Throw New InvalidCustomerException
> End If
> ```

According this [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/410336) value types passed into `IsNothing` function will be boxed and the function will always return false.

Having this the first part in the `If` expression in my example will always return false (Guid is value type).

So is it correct if I rewrite that code to just the following?:

```vb
If customerID.Equals(System.Guid.Empty) Then
    Throw New InvalidCustomerException
End If
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter Please put your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: The bigger cue that there is something fishy about this code is that it uses Or instead of OrElse.  Only OrElse could prevent a NullReferenceException.  Just complete the Q+A you started with your own post and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @HansPassant But in my case Guid is not nullable so NullReferenceException shouldn't occur, should it?